How to sum a std::range?
Is there a way to sum a C++20 range other than iterating over it?
I solve problems from Project Euler to improve my C++ skills, and wanted to solve problem 37 using the std::ranges library.
My code looks something like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

bool is_truncatable(const int n)
{
    // Blah blah...
}

int truncatable_primes()
{
    const auto range = views::iota(10); // Goes on to infinity.
    const int total_num_of_truncatable_primes = 11; // Given.
    auto all_truncatable_primes = range | views::filter([] (int n) { return is_truncatable(n); }) 
                                        | views::take(total_num_of_truncatable_primes);
    
    const int sum = accumulate(all_truncatable_primes.begin(), all_truncatable_primes.end(), 0); // Does not compile.

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    const auto answer = truncatable_primes();
    cout << answer << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Since there is no ranges::accumulate yet, is there an idiomatic way to sum the all_truncatable_primes range, or am I forced to use a for loop?

std::ranges::fold_left(rng, 0, std::plus<>{});. There's a fold_right and a fold_left_first for none-empty ranges. But its C++23.

all_truncatable_primes is not a common_range, which means that its begin() and end() have different types.
This is incompatible with C++98 algorithms that require both to be of the same type (such as std::accumulate). One alternative is to apply views::common to make it a common_range:
auto all_truncatable_primes = range | views::filter([] (int n) { return is_truncatable(n); }) 
                                    | views::take(total_num_of_truncatable_primes)
                                    | views::common;
const int sum = accumulate(all_truncatable_primes.begin(), all_truncatable_primes.end(), 0);

A more appropriate way is to use C++23 ranges::fold_left which can be seen as a range version of std::accumulate:
auto all_truncatable_primes = range | views::filter([] (int n) { return is_truncatable(n); }) 
                                    | views::take(total_num_of_truncatable_primes);
const int sum = ranges::fold_left(all_truncatable_primes, 0, std::plus{});


You might add | views::common to ba able to use it with std algorithm:
auto all_truncatable_primes = range | views::filter([] (int n) { return is_truncatable(n); }) 
                                    | views::take(total_num_of_truncatable_primes)
                                    | views::common;

const int sum = accumulate(all_truncatable_primes.begin(), all_truncatable_primes.end(), 0);

Demo
